# Remove string if not followed by another string

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a data frame where I do some string replacing for example:

```
df1["Restriction"] = df1["Restriction"].str.replace("vs", "&")
```

which results in something like this:

```
Restriction
Montreal & Vancouver
Montreal &
```

What I would like to do is remove the & if it is not followed by another string so it would result  in the following:

```
Restriction
Montreal & Vancouver
Montreal
```

I thought about slicing the last characters but then that would slice for everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df1["Restriction"] = df1["Restriction"].str.replace("vs", "&").str.rstrip("& ")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) :

```
df1["Restriction"] = df1["Restriction"].str.replace("&$","")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `vs` to be part of a partial word, you can use a regex with an alternation and a capture group, and surround vs with word boundaries `\b`

In the capture group, match vs till the end of the string, or else match vs as an alternative. If capture group 1 exists, replace with an empty string, else replace with &

```
import pandas as pd

texts = [
    "Montreal vs Vancouver",
    "Montreal vs",
    "devs"
]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(texts, columns=["Restriction"])

df1['Restriction'] = df1['Restriction'].str.replace(
    r'(\s*\bvs\s*$)|\bvs\b',
    lambda m: '' if m.group(1) else '&'
)

print(df1)
```

Output

```
            Restriction
0  Montreal & Vancouver
1              Montreal
2                  devs
```